# Exchange server 2013 show my internal ip instead of public ip in SMTP hello

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2013

I have tested my SMTP and the result was this:

```
Connecting to 82.137.244.184
220 MX-S.Sindyan-sy.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 30 May       2019 05:49:46 +0300 [709 ms]
EHLO keeper-us-east-1c.mxtoolbox.com
250-MX-S.Sindyan-sy.com Hello [192.168.100.25]
 250-SIZE 37748736
  250-PIPELINING
 250-DSN
 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 250-STARTTLS
 250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
 250-AUTH NTLM
 250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
  250-8BITMIME
  250-BINARYMIME
  250-CHUNKING
  250 XRDST [756 ms]
  MAIL FROM:<supertool@mxtoolbox.com>
  250 2.1.0 Sender OK [762 ms]
   RCPT TO:<test@mxtoolboxsmtpdiag.com>
    550 5.7.1 Unable to relay [5757 ms]
```

The problem is here:

```
MX-S.Sindyan-sy.com Hello [192.168.100.25]
```

It should be my public ip, not internal ip. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem. That is in fact the ip address of the server. This is the ip address that the server will identify itself with during the SMTP HELO/EHLO. It has nothing to do with sending or receiving email and is not the ip address that external SMTP servers will try to connect to. It is simply the server saying "Hello, my name is X."

Answer (score 0):

I remember this issue, spent a lot of time tracing it down. The Microsoft guys will tell you all about how to edit your send and receive connectors. And on the general tab of the connector there is indeed a place to edit the hostname. But, this does not stop it from providing your internal IP address. Microsoft doesn't seem to think that is a problem, and they apparently aren't going to do anything about it.  This may be a possible solution for you: [headerrewriter](https://ivasoft.com/headerrewriter.shtml) but it is not free. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with joeqwerty, the result does not have any effect. The SMTP HELO clause is the stage of the SMTP protocol where a SMTP server introduce themselves to each other. The sending server will identify who it is.